# Python Class With Lots of Instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, instance

I need to define a class and lots of instances (more than 30, but 3 of them are given in the code) to be able to share them between python module files. I have problem with the following code (simplified):

```
class class1:
    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = var1

    def read_file():
        try:
            f = open('/file1.txt')
            read_text = f.readlines()
            abc1 = class1((read_text[0]))
            abc2 = class1((read_text[1]))
            abc3 = class1((read_text[2]))
    
        except:
            abc1 = class1("text_1")
            abc2 = class1("text_2")
            abc3 = class1("text_3")


class1.read_file()

def1 = class1("abc")
def2 = class1("def")
def3 = class1("hjk")

print(def1.var1)
print(abc1.var1)
print(abc2.var1)
```

It gives the error:

```
NameError: name 'abc1' is not defined
```

I tried to define instances in the class in order to avoid defining instances for them and making the code long.

What is the pythonic way to define more than 30 instances via a class?
What is the solution for defining the instances in the class?

Content of the file1.txt:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Comment: In your print statements `abc1` and `abc2` should be `def2` and `def3`, I think? `abc{1,2,3}` are only available in the method `class1.read_file()`, nowhere else.

Comment: `abc1` etc only exist in the scope of the function, you are trying to refer to it ouside the function where it doesnt exits

Comment: @Alex, No, they are different things.

Comment: As Chris said, the variables `abc1`, `abc2`, and `abc3` are only available in the `read_file` function. You cannot access them like this unless you make them attributes of `class1` but then they will not be instances of `class1` themselves.

Comment: @Alex, what do you suggest for instances more than 30 in a class for the code to be more pythonic? (I have lots of python module files also there will be a lot of classes and instances will be shared between the modules. I will convert my function-oriented code into class code.)

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you expect to happen. You should edit/update your question with what you expect to be able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var


with open('/file1.txt') as f:
    objects = [MyClass(line) for line in f]

print(objects[0].var)
print(objects[1].var)
```

(let's give PEP8 name to the class)
To define "many instances in pythonic way" you may want to use list comprehension.

Comment: As I understand, defining instances in this way is a correct way. Am I right? (I mean using this structure both in my first post and your answer.) I will accept this as answer since it answers one of my questions.

Comment: Yes, correct. This is how you can create multiple instances based on multiple inputs(here file lines)